# Move renderings issue

Tags: experience-editor

Sitecore 8.0 (150812)

It looks like move rendering button in the Experience Editor isn't working for me.

[image: 1 step]

[image: step 2]

[image: step3]

[image: step 4]
[image: step 5]

Comment: Can you try to remove any custom css and or js? Often this conflicts with stuff in the Experience Editor

Comment: @KoenHeye I've already tried to do it on clean sitecore with the same version.

Comment: @Vlad have you reported as a bug at http://support.sitecore.net/ ?

Comment: @tamas not yet.

Comment: Is that one placeholder with 4 stacked components or 4 placeholders? Are you using dynamic placeholders?